# How to find the Value of the Limit $ \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin\alpha x-\sin\beta x}{e^{\alpha x}-e^{\beta x}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am familiar with indeterminate limits which can be solved using L'Hospital Rule, but I cannot use that in this case.

Comment: If you explain why you cannot use L'Hospital Rule to find given limit, then people may easily know where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose that $\alpha \ne \beta$. Note that $\sin$ and $\exp$ are differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, and we can use the mean value theorem. There are $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$ in $(\alpha x,\beta x)\cup (\beta x,\alpha x)$ such that
$$
\sin \alpha x - \sin\beta x=(\alpha x-\beta x)\cos \gamma_1,\qquad e^{\alpha x}-e^{\beta x}=(\alpha x-\beta x)e^{\gamma_2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you know $\sin{x}\sim x$ and $e^x \sim x+1$ both as $x\to0$.
Then
$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin\alpha x-\sin\beta x}{e^{\alpha x}-e^{\beta x}}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin\beta x(\dfrac{\sin{\alpha x}}{\sin{\beta x}}-1)}{(e^{\beta x}-1)(\dfrac{e^{\alpha x}-1}{e^{\beta x}-1}-1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the rules of L'Hospital we get $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\alpha\cos(\alpha x)-\beta\cos(\beta x)}{\alpha e^{\alpha x}-\beta e^{\beta x}}$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

If you are against using L'Hospital, you may just expand the functions.

In the limit $\eta x\to0$
$$
\sin(\eta x) \approx \eta x + O(x^3)\\
\exp(\eta x) \approx 1 + \eta x + O(x^2)
$$
You should be able to continue from here ...

Answer (score 0):

W/O  L'Hospital and Series Expansion,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin2ax-\sin2bx}{e^{2ax}-e^{2bx}}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{2\sin(a-b)x}{e^{2(a-b)x}-1}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\cos(a+b)x}{e^{2bx}}$$

$$=\dfrac{\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(a-b)x}{(a-b)x}}{\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{2(a-b)x}-1}{2(a-b)x}}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem we see that the expression under limit is equal to $\dfrac{\cos c} {e^c} $ where $c$ lies between $\alpha x$ and $\beta x$. As $x\to 0$ we have $c\to 0$ and the desired limit is equal to $1$.